# Lualatex print \\par stopped producing the result

Tags: luatex

The `\par` option stopped working in `lualatex` in 2019.

`tex.print(-2,x .. "\\par")` produces only `\par` in the final text, no paragraph break.

`File.txt` may be any text file with `^` and `&` to mark the beginning and end of the selected text.

It used to work in `MacTex2018`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{luacode,luatextra,luaotfload}
\usepackage[lutf8x]{luainputenc}


\begin{luacode*}

function readtxt()
file = io.open("File.txt", "r")
text = file:read("*all")
file:close()
for x in string.gmatch(text, "^(.-)&") do
tex.print(-2,x .. "\\par")
end
end

\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}
\directlua{readtxt()}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you think the `-2` in `tex.print` does?

Comment: You will want to use `tex.sprint(-2,x) tex.sprint("\\par")`.

Comment: it is not needed to load luaotfload, luatextra and luainputenc nowadays.

Comment: Many thanks, it is all working again. 1. Having no `\usepackage{luacode,luatextra,luaotfload}` did not work on Mactex_2019 with Lualatex, still had to include it. The rest worked out. I have found no information on the -2 option in the manuals. Any help?

Comment: @DmitryStarostin Quote: “The optional parameter can be used to print the strings using the catcode regime defined by `\catcodetable` n. If n is -1, the currently active catcode regime is used. If n is -2, the resulting catcodes are the result of `\the\toks`: all category codes are 12 (other) except for the space character, that has category code 10 (space).” Your `\par` output by `tex.print(-2, ... "\\par")` was made of four character tokens of category 12 (other). This is not the `\par` control sequence token.

Comment: @DmitryStarostin - Do note that Ulrike did *not* say that loading `luacode` was unnecessary for your example code to compile. What she was telling you is that the *other three* packages that are loaded in the preamble -- `luaotfload`, `luatextra` and `luainputenc` -- are not needed.